# tx.wait() never resolves using ethers library

Tags: tokens, contract-deployment, pancakeswap, ethers.js

I am using ethers library in my nodejs , and trying to call a function in smartcontract  which looks like:

```
    const tx = await router.swapETHForExactTokens(
            amountOut, 
            [bnb,bip20],
            reciverAddress,
            Date.now() + 1000*60*10, // 10 min
            overrides
            )
    const receipt = await tx.wait();
    console.log('Transaction receipt', receipt);
```

This never gets resolved,  result in my transaction is never broadcasted to the network. Any way around for this?

Comment: Does the account you're using to send the TX have any ETH to pay for gas?

Comment: Also, are you using Mainnet or another chain?

Comment: @scorpion9979 yes it has some of them, i am using Binance chain, and here is my address used to execute the trnx https://bscscan.com/address/0xdab949f898d9f6b73048a95d14515ffcca2e6bf8